# FMX Change Coordinate System

Tags: delphi, coordinates, firemonkey, pascal, cartesian

I want to change Delphi FMX's coordinate system (for visual controls like TImage, TPaintBox, etc) to use Cartesian coordinate system (Bottom Left)

[image: Cartesian coordinate system]

How can I do this?

This is very basic for GDI:

```
HDC hDC = this->Canvas->Handle;
SetMapMode(hDC, MM_LOENGLISH); //Change coordinate system
SetViewportOrgEx(hDC, 300, 200, NULL); //Change origin
```

Coordinate point change sample for Delphi FMX:

```
Image1.Position.Point := PointF(250, 250);
```

Comment: The only way I can come up with is with a lot of CLASS HELPERs that redefine the various properties/methods and then re-calculates the coordinates before sending them on to the original properties/methods. It'll be a lot of code...

Comment: I draw a lot of lines (line, circle, arc, ellipse, beizer (curve/cubic vs..) ).
It's hard to calculate the coordinates for all.

This is very basic for GDI.
HDC hDC = this->Canvas->Handle;
SetMapMode(hDC, MM_LOENGLISH); //Change coordinate system
SetViewportOrgEx(hDC, 300, 200, NULL); //Change origin

Comment: Paint to a buffer and mirror it in the y-axis before assigning it to the control canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed one can set a negative scale (at one or both axes) in FMX resulting in flipping things in the respective axes coordinates.

So to reverse the Y axis you need to do

```
SomeContainer.Scale.Point := TPointF.Create(0, -1);
```

after that you'd also need to offset though, but could do it by offseting a parent control by (-width/2, -height/2) I guess